# iPhone: stretch gradient image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I hava a UIButton. And for my button I want to set image with vertical gradient.
[image]

Button can change it width and height, so I need to make image stretchable. I found method like:

```
UIImage* myGradientImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientImage.png"];
UIImage* stretchImage = [myGradientImage
    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:20];
```

When button width grows its stretched ok. But if height grows, gradient looks not very good.
[image]

Is there any possibility to set bottomCapHeight and topCapHeight together ? Or to say to image do not touch center of image ?

Comment: Which function do you use to set the UIButton image : setImage:forState: or setBackgroundImage:forState: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
UIImage* stretchImage = [myGradientImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 
                                                             topCapHeight:0];
```

The height will stretch uniformly, which will look fine if you give a high-res original image.

If your rounded corners are in the image, however, this will make them non-circular. To get around that, supply your gradient image without rounded corners, then do

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```